# How to pass an input of a function into another function without the input being asked twice?

Tags: python, function, input

How do I pass an input of a function into another function without the input being asked twice. My code looks like that:

```
def function():
    signal_0 = 1
    signal_1 = input("0 or 1?")
    select = 0
    output = (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1)
    return output, select

def connection(func): 
    eingang = func()[0]
    return eingang 


print(function())
print(connection(function))
```

what I would like to happen is, that `print(connection(function))` does not ask `input("0 or 1?")` again.

It should take the input that was asked in `function` already so if I have 1 as input `signal_1 = 1` in `connection(function)`

Comment: What do you mean "it does not ask ... again"? When I run it it asks me...

Comment: Every time `function` is run, it will ask for input. If you don't want that to happen, you'd need to do something like ask for input outside of the function, and pass `signal_1` in as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it is:

```
def function(flag=1):
    signal_0 = 1
    if flag==0:
        signal_1 = input("0 or 1?")
    select = 0
    output = (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1)
    return output, select

def connection(func): 
    eingang = func()[0]
    return eingang 


print(function(0))


print(connection(function))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global variable`

```py
signal_1 = None

def function():
    global signal_1
    signal_0 = 1
    signal_1 = input("0 or 1?") if not signal_1 else signal_1
    select = 0
    output = (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1) # check if the value is already initialized. If yes then don't take input
    return output, select

def connection(func): 
    eingang = func()[0]
    return eingang 


print(function())
print(connection(function))
```

Comment: Using global variables is generally frowned upon as they can lead to namespace pollution.

Comment: Yes that is true @DapperDuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the following:

1. instantiate a global variable -to hold the input- to none.
2. Inside "function", use the keyword "global" to operate on the variable in the global scope.
3. Create a conditional inside "function": to check whether the global variable still has "None" value -which will be the case if function has never been called- or not.

The following is an example implementation:

```
signal_1= None

def function():
    global signal_1
    signal_0 =0
    signal_1 = input("0 or 1?") if signal_1==None else signal_1
    select = 0
    return (not select and signal_0) or (select and signal_1), select
```